# Remote debugger: The specified account does not exist

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

I'm trying to setup the remote debugger.

No matter what I do, visual studio keeps saying "The specified account does not exist".

Environment:

Domain, Windows 2008 R2 DC.

Both PCs joined the domain.

Remote PC is windows server 2003 R2 SP2, 32 bits, running on a HyperV machine.

Local PC is Windows 7 SP1, 64 bits, visual studio 2010, running on physical hardware

I'm using the same user account to log on locally, to log on to the remote PC, and to run the "Visual Studio 10 Remote Debugger" service. This user account is domain administrator.

If it matters, the subnets are different (one is 192.168.0.xxx another one is 192.168.1.xxx) but the RRaS on the server routes traffic between them, both ping and remote desktop works both directions.

Things I've tried:

- Run remote debugger as s service, and as an application.
- Add rule to windows firewall on the local PC. The remote PC has no firewall (the service is stopped).
- Re-join remote PC to the domain.

What should I do to make remote debugger work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try creating local accounts on both machines with the same username and password as your domain account.

Comment: Try attaching the debugger while the remote debugger is not running and see if this gives you a different error message, that way you are at least sure the connection works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the visual studio project settings, use IP address instead of the host name.

It seems when the remote host name is long and contains dashes (and/or possibly there are some other factors I'm not aware of, such as IPv6, or different OS on local and remote machines), visual studio is unable to resolve it, and fails to connect saying "The specified account does not exist".

To workaround just specify the numeric IP address instead of the host name after the "@", i.e. replace "MYCOMPANY\Const@DEV-EC2S-4" with "MYCOMPANY\Const@192.168.3.204".